# Where do I get the list of tags on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

How do I get the list of tags with description in Stack Overflow?

The description provided there is great, but right now I am allowed to ask questions only once in a week, so I can't go through the tags I wanted to. Those definitions are really sophisticated and awesome, but where do I read it any place here?

Comment: Via the tags button on the top right of this page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: tags]

Click in the [**Tags**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) button on the right corner of the page.

Comment: need more freehand circles for this to be a perfect answer.